# Invoke a bot message when the user has not specified a nickname

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to write

> Error, you did not specify a nickname.

My code:

```
if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'kill'):
    name = message.mentions[0]
    randomgif = random.choice(["https://i.imgur.com/Pk6lOwI.gif","https://i.imgur.com/IRoF2pJ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/dV2N6KJ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/xyhP7Rz.gif","https://i.imgur.com/CzpHqFX.gif","https://i.imgur.com/iBsrA1c.gif","https://i.imgur.com/4jHevGp.gif","https://i.imgur.com/Oy2XGuL.gif","https://i.imgur.com/1uQwyli.gif","https://i.imgur.com/uCUf0V5.gif","https://i.imgur.com/xfubfyv.gif","https://i.imgur.com/8th0trO.gif","https://i.imgur.com/2jOXQcP.gif","https://i.imgur.com/2kCGfie.gif","https://i.imgur.com/TPV6Upz.gif","https://i.imgur.com/Bti43x8.gif"])
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x008C8C)
    embed.set_author(name= message.author.display_name + " убил " + name.display_name, icon_url='https://pre00.deviantart.net/7e08/th/pre/f/2017/125/2/2/felix_argyle_by_aramisdraws-db8847i.png')
    embed.set_image(url= randomgif)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`Member.nick` is the server-specific nickname of a member.  If there is no such name, it will be None.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if member.nick is None:
        await bot.say("Error!  You did not specify a nickname")
        return
    randomgif = random.choice(["https://i.imgur.com/Pk6lOwI.gif","https://i.imgur.com/IRoF2pJ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/dV2N6KJ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/xyhP7Rz.gif","https://i.imgur.com/CzpHqFX.gif","https://i.imgur.com/iBsrA1c.gif","https://i.imgur.com/4jHevGp.gif","https://i.imgur.com/Oy2XGuL.gif","https://i.imgur.com/1uQwyli.gif","https://i.imgur.com/uCUf0V5.gif","https://i.imgur.com/xfubfyv.gif","https://i.imgur.com/8th0trO.gif","https://i.imgur.com/2jOXQcP.gif","https://i.imgur.com/2kCGfie.gif","https://i.imgur.com/TPV6Upz.gif","https://i.imgur.com/Bti43x8.gif"])
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x008C8C)
    embed.set_author(name= ctx.message.author.display_name + " убил " + member.display_name, icon_url='https://pre00.deviantart.net/7e08/th/pre/f/2017/125/2/2/felix_argyle_by_aramisdraws-db8847i.png')
    embed.set_image(url= randomgif)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

If you're implementing commands, you should be using the `discord.ext.commands` module, that's what it's for.

Comment: First `bot.say` needs an `await`